# Gmail Recipients aren't seeing company logo next to email in inbox

Tags: marketing-cloud, gmail

My company uses Salesforce Marketing Cloud to send our emails to our customers. Recently we noticed that our company logo does not appear next to our emails in the inbox of the Gmail app.

From searching online there appears to be a lot of back and forth on this issue but not a lot of solutions. One of the main solutions I have found is that this image that shows up is tied back to your companies Google+ account. My company does have a Google+ account and so to test if this was the case we changed our profile picture to see if it would update for non-gmail users and it did.

Another thing we noticed is that we are sending our emails to non-gmail users via a different sender profile in salesforce marketing cloud than we use for gmail users. I opened a support ticket with Salesforce and they stated that this was not something that they were able to aide in and that I should reach out to Google. Has anyone here dealt with this or a similar issue, and if so what did you do to solve or workaround the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About the first part: Gmail has rolled out a new feature that allows us to embed microdata to annotate emails, including that image. I suspect this is going to be the way to go moving forward. It should work in the Gmail apps for now, and eventually the desktop clients.

**Info and test utility:**
https://developers.google.com/gmail/promotab/

(FYI: SFMC strips out script tags, so go with the standard HTML div approach.)

Here is some additional information from Litmus.

https://litmus.com/blog/how-to-utilize-the-power-of-gmails-new-promotions-tab

Comment: Thank you! This appears to be just what I was searching for, I appreciate the help.